# Custom Column in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

Can someone please help me with custom column code in Power BI Query Editor.
I wish to get a value "Latest" in custom column against "CRTG-0006" as 0006 is the highest number in the column. CRTG-0006 is the latest version of the Program CRTG & CRTG-0001 being the first version of the Program. In future, let's say if I add "CRTG-0007" file in the root folder, Custom Column return value shall be "Latest" for "CRTG-0007" and shall be "null" for "CRTG-0006" and all previous versions of the Program.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your layout,

- Assume your program and versions column header is `Program`
- Assume your preceding step is `#"Changed Step`
- Then, in the Add Custom Column dialog you can use this formula:

```
if [Program] = List.Max(#"Changed Type"[Program]) then "Latest" else null
```

[image]

*This works because your format is such that simple alphabetical sorting will work.  The program name/abbreviation is always the same, and the version number is padded with zero's*

By the way, if you have multiple programs in the Program column, I would group by the program base name, and apply the same algorithm in a custom aggregation.

Comment: Thanks for the solution Ron. What if I replace CRTG-0001 with CRTG-BL, how would you be able to use list.max function? I get error in my sample data because I have an entry with "-BL" at the end unfortunately.

Comment: @ProjectInsights What to do will depend on how you determine the **latest** when you have that kind of suffix.

Comment: I would say if text exists as suffix, then **ignore it** from the calculation [or consider it to be the **first**] & do list.max calculation on the remaining data with  number as a suffix.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to tell what you want but you can right click then split the column on - to get the number.  You can then convert type to numerical and sort or take the List.Max([ColumnName])

Comment: Thanks for the solution horseyride. What if I replace CRTG-0001 with CRTG-BL, how would you be able to use list.max function? I get error in my sample data because I have an entry with "-BL" at the end unfortunately.

Comment: If there just one, then post split you can // filter out alpha // replace error // or //  convert letters to a 0 or 9 depending on how you want it to evaluate

Comment: That said, depending on if you want alpha to be before or after numerical, by default, alpha sorts after numerical, so if you just sort without splitting and take first item, that would be something to compare to   max = Table.Sort(#"PreviousStepName",{{"Column1", Order.Descending}}){0}[Column1]